# closing file after creating list > text = open("path/file.ext").read().split()

Tags: python, list, file-io, split

I used the following line in a program.

```
text = open("C:\Python27\Scripts\wordlist.txt", "r").read().split()
```

This creates a list called text. My question is, is there still an open file that needs closing? Or is it not necessary in this case, or perhaps not really possible... I tried looking through locals() and globals() for any 'file' type object, but there was none. Would such a line of code be considered bad practice for some reason? On the surface, for my purposes, it seemed rather handy. (the wordlist.txt is a lengthy tome)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes I would consider this bad practice. Best practice to use when handling files is to use the [with statement](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm). The code would then look something like this

```
with open("C:\Python27\Scripts\wordlist.txt", "r") as textfile:
    result = textfile.read.split()
```

Using the with statement implicitly means that the file will be closed upon leaving the scope, so you don't have to worry about it. Read the above link for more information on how it works!

Answer (score 2):

It should be closed, but just note that a [`with`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) statement is much more pythonic and better to use, because it is guaranteed to close the file, even if an error is raised:

```
with open("C:\Python27\Scripts\wordlist.txt") as myfile: # Second argument not needed. 'r' is by default
    text = myfile.read().split()
```